# Why I can get mysql.js in node CLI but not in command line

Tags: node.js, windows, mysqljs

I installed mysql.js through npm in Windows 10, however I get mysql module in node.js CLI but not from the command line. I tried the sample code which is given at the official mysql.js website with my local configuration, and it produces a successful connection and a `module not found` error. I'm at a loss to understand where it's going wrong.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'mysql'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (d:\projects\prj_nodetest\234.js:1:77)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
```

I also tried the file with only one line as:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');
```

with the same error.

Comment: Help us help you - share the code and the full error message / stacktrace.

Comment: I use this in command line

Comment: C:\Program Files\nodejs>node d:\projects\prj_nodetest\234.js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:583
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'mysql'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (d:\projects\prj_nodetest\234.js:1:77)
     I also tried the file only has const mysql = require('mysql'); and resulting in the sam error. Thanks

Comment: It's really hard to make out anything like that. Please [edit] you question and add this information in. Additionally, can you share the contents of your `node_modules` directory?

Comment: Thanks Mureinik. I've already make change on my question